# Daframe print as str instead of dict

Tags: pandas

data frame is below

```
flag
{'a':True,'b':False}
{'a':False,'b':True}
```

code

```
s = [x  for x in df['flag']]
for i in s:
    print (i)
    print (type(i))
```

Output is below

```
{'a':True,'b':False}

<class 'str'>

{'a':False,'b':True}

<class 'str'>
```

I need to print data type as   `<class 'dict'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eval(i)`  or

```
     import ast
     ast.literal_eval(i)
```

in your for loop

Answer (score 0):

While creating dataframe, the dictionaries were probably passed in as strings instead of dict which is why you are getting type `<class 'str'>` instead of `<class 'dict'>`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'flag':["{'a':True,'b':False}","{'a':False,'b':True}"]})
```

gives:

```
{'a':True,'b':False}
<class 'str'>
{'a':False,'b':True}
<class 'str'>
```

and this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'flag':[{'a':True,'b':False},{'a':False,'b':True}]})
```

gives:

```
{'a': True, 'b': False}
<class 'dict'>
{'a': False, 'b': True}
<class 'dict'>
```